# ArrayAdapter not creating views

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have an `ArrayAdapter` that needs to populate `listView`. Here is the code

```
final ArrayAdapter<CarDetails.Extra> aditionalListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<CarDetails.Extra>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, CurrentRequest
                    .getCarDetalized().getExtra()) {
        class TagHolder {
            TextView extraName;
            TextView extraPrice;

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, final View convertView,
                final ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            TagHolder tagHolder = null;
            if (v == null) {
                final LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.additional_component, null);

                tagHolder = new TagHolder();
                tagHolder.extraName = (TextView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.additional_info);
                tagHolder.extraPrice = (TextView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.additional_price);
                v.setTag(tagHolder);
            } else {
                tagHolder = (TagHolder) v.getTag();
            }
            try {
                final CarDetails.Extra extra = getItem(position);
                tagHolder.extraName.setText(extra.getName());
                tagHolder.extraPrice.setText(extra.getCurrency() + " "
                        + extra.getPrice());
                Log.d("Adapter",
                        "Set up adapter field with name " + extra.getName());

            } catch (final Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(0);
                Log.e("CarList", "Error setting cell" + e);
            }
            return v;
        }

    };
    additionalInfoList.setAdapter(aditionalListAdapter);
```

The getExtra() method returns `ArrayList` with objects. It has 18 objects as LogCat says. It runs normally on Android Emulator 4.2.2, but it doesn't work on my device 4.0.4. It just populates one(the first) object and that'it. I tried overriding `getCount()` method and set return to 18, it doesn't do anything too. Where is the problem?

Comment: Have you used the debugger or at least the LogCat on your 4.0.4 device? What did you find?

Comment: The arraylist has 18 views, but getView() is calles only for first one.

Comment: So, you haven't used the debugger? Do you see any error print outs or just "Set up adapter field with name ___" once?

Comment: Just did it. It iterates through getView() 3 times using only first item

Comment: That is odd, what happens if you create a subclass rather than an anonymous inner class?

Comment: it is the same. I tried it on multiple devices, the results are the same.